# Grep search for binary data

Tags: grep, pcre

Why does this command work

```
echo -ne "\x74\x79\xf4"|grep -aPo "\x74\x79"
```

and this doesn't?

```
echo -ne "\x74\x79\xf4"|grep -aPo "\x74\x79\xf4"
```

Comment: perhaps because `\xf4` is some sort of non-ASCII character or something?  `echo -ne "\x74\x79\xf4" | LC_ALL=C grep -aPo "\x74\x79\xf4"` should work

Comment: `echo 'tyô' | grep -aPo "\x74\x79\xf4"` works

Answer (score 2):

The following will work:

```
echo -ne "\x74\x79\xC3\xB4" | grep -aPo "\x74\x79\xf4"
#                  ^^^^^^^
echo -ne "\x74\x79\u00F4" | grep -aPo "\x74\x79\xf4"
#                 ^^^^^^
```

The `\xF4` is not a single byte, it consists of two bytes, `C3` and `B4`. Thus, to encode it properly in the `echo` command, you need to use `\xC3\xB4` sequence.

With `\u00F4`, you specify the code unit.